# database design to include 'no value' row for product category

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am designing a products database with tables mainCategory, category and subCategory. Some products will not have a category or subCategory therefore
the category and subCategory tables have to hold a 'no category' and a 'no sub category' value.
There is a one to many relationship between mainCategory and category and a one to many relationship between category and Subcategory.

this means that I have a 'no category' value for every mainCategory and a 'no sub category' value for every category.

As you can see the subCategory table holds mostly 'no sub category' values.
Is there another way to do this that would not create a row for every mainCategory in the category table and for every category in the subCategory table ?

I need a 'no category' value for every mainCategory because when I do a

```
select * from category where mainCategoryId = x;
```

I need to get a 'no category' value (in this case textid 17)
the same is true for

```
select * from subCategory where categoryId = x;
```

I need to get a 'no sub category' value (in this case textid 18)

textId 17 = no category
textId 18 = no sub category

mainCategory table

```
id  textId
1   3
2   16
```

category table

```
id  mainCategoryId  textId
1   1   4
2   1   5
3   1   6
4   1   17
5   2   17
```

subCategory table

```
id  categoryId  textId
1   3   7
2   3   8
3   1   18
4   2   18
5   3   18
6   4   18
7   5   18
```

Comment: What exactly does `textId` correlate to? It doesn't seem to be related to any of the three categories, and shouldn't be needed at all. Is that saying that some products have the same text to describe them? Because that seems strange in and of itself.

Comment: the textid refers to a row in a different table 'text'. Because this is for a site with multiple languages the text must have an textid and a language id.
textId 17 = no category textId 18 = no sub category (in english) 
another alternative I thought about was to use NULL as the value for 'no category' and 'no sub category' but that would not eliminate my need to create the rows that I need now.
edited original post to explain better.

Comment: In that case I wouldn't worry about a special value for categories and sub-categories that don't contain a value. Just assign the sub-categories to reference their respective categories, and in the case of a product not having a category, simply leave those fields empty (`null`). There shouldn't be any reason why you can't do that :)

Comment: my problem is that when selecting a mainCategory there must be an option to select 'no category' for the category value of a product.
The only other way I think I can do this is by having to execute 2 seperate sql statements. the first statement to select all the category values and the second statement to select the 'no category' value.

Comment: You could always do a `SELECT  .. WHERE mainCategoryId = NULL`, which would prevent you from having to define an entirely new category :)